# Set foreign key on new/create action in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Alright so I'm pretty new to this rails stuff so please bear with me...

I'm trying to make the most simple application ever, a Christmas list, and I need a little bit of help. Let me fill you in:

I scaffolded a person and an item. I modified my models a little bit and here is what they look like.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :item, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
end

class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :items do |t|
      t.integer :person_id
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreatePeople < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :people do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Seems like that's all cool. The index action on the people_controller lists all the people(duh)

```
<% @people.each do |person| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= link_to person.name, "/people/#{person.id}" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

and when you click on one, it calls the show action(same controller) which gets all of the items for that person

```
def show
  @person = Person.find(params[:id])
  @items = Item.where(:person_id => params[:id])

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @person }
  end
end
```

and pulls the show view

```
<table>
<% @items.each do |item| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= item.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_item_path %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Remove', "" %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>
<br/>
<%= link_to 'Add', :controller => :items, :action => :new, :id => @person.id %>
```

The link at the bottom is to add a new item for the person who's summary we are viewing. So then in the new action on the items_controller I have:

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @item.person_id = params[:id]

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # new.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @item }
  end
end
```

Now I know this doesn't get saved until @item.save is called. I imagine this happens from the _form.html.erb submit button which in turn calls the create action in the controller?

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(params[:item])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @item.save
      format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

I'm just a little confused why this is never getting set, it seems like it should be so easy(I'm sure it is haha). Also while I'm at it, you may have noticed I have no link for my 'Remove' link above. This is because I also couldn't figure out how to destroy action from that link to remove the correct item.

Like I said, this is all new to me. I appreciate any help! Please feel free to critique EVERYTHING I have done here. I don't have feelings :)

Comment: I don't quite understand the question, but one thing that's wrong for sure is `has_many :item` should be `has_many :items`

Comment: Also, `render json:` everywhere should be `:render json =>`

Comment: In your new method, you can simplify by `Item.new({ :person_id => params[:id] })`

Comment: I guess the question was just: Why when I set the person_id the way I did, does it not get saved to the database? And is this where I should be setting it? Does this seem like the proper approach for such a simple application?

Comment: Also, why do the 'render json:' things need to change? I didn't even put those in there. The generate scaffold did that for me I think

Comment: In your new method? The object is not being saved without calling @item.save (or instead you can use Item.create instead of Item.new)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Vibhu said, it's quite likely your issue stem from the fact that you should have `has_many :items` (note the plural) in your `Person` controller.

To add a hidden filed in your form specifying the person's id, add this in your creation form:

```
f.hidden_field :person_id
```

Comment: OK I think I figured out what was going wrong here. I had removed
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :person_id %><br />
  <%= f.text_field :person_id %>
</div>
from the _from.html.erb because when adding an item, the user doesn't really care about what the person_id is. After adding this back in, the save works as expected, but I dont want it this way. How do I save this foreign key without having a form field for it?

Comment: Using a hidden field in a form is one way. However, it allows user to change it (by using firebug or some other tool).

If you have nested your items resources inside person people resources, then you can set the person id in create action as mentioned by Vibhu. This is the recommended and more secure way of setting foreign key.

Comment: Yes, but the `id` param could be overwritten anyway. In any case, object access should be authorized (e.g. with CanCan).

Comment: Cool guys appreciate the help. Bit of a learning curve moving from .NET desktop apps to rails web apps, but it's starting to make sense. Thanks again!